# Give the derived class the ability to implement only a selected number of base classes' properties

Tags: c#, oop, strategy-pattern

First, I'd like to describe the problem I want to solve:

I want to make a program to handle legal civil cases. In each legal case there's a `List<IDocument> LegalDocuments` containing objects for any and all documents that might be in this legal case. Each document is derived from basic `Document` class and implements `IDocument` interface. The amount of possible document types is open and could expand well beyond 100. There are also few common properties in the base class that documents implement, here's the class:

```
public abstract class Document
{
    //some general properties that all documents implement

    
    //The expiration date of a document
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    // The series of a document
    public string DocSeries { get; set; }
    //The serial number of a document
    public int DocNumber { get; set; }
    //the amount of money associated with the document
    public decimal MoneyAmount { get; set; }
    // signer of the document The exemplar of LegalSubject is presented below.
    public LegalSubject Signer;
}

public class LegalSubject 
{
 //LegalSubject implementation
}
```

The problem is: not all documents have all of the presented properties. Examples:

```
//passport: Has: ExpirationDate, DocSeries, DocNumber. 
//Doesn't have: MoneyAmount, Signer
public class Passport : Document, ILegalDocument { }

//Payment Order: Has: DocNumber, MoneyAmount
// Doesn't have: The rest
public class PaymentOrder : Document, ILegalDocument { }

//Power of Attorney: Has: ExpirationDate, Signer
//Doesn't have: The rest
public class PowerOfAttorney : Document, ILegalDocument { }

// The common interface for the documents to fit into the list.
public interface ILegalDocument { }
```

The idea is that outside code should test wheither a certain document has a certain property and depending on the result enable/disable corresponding UserForm control (for example).

The only sensible way I could think of is a Strategy pattern, where I move implementation of each property each to a separate class  and implement them through interfaces , here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ExampleLegalDocuments
{


    public class Passport : Document, ILegalDocument 
    { 
        public Passport()
        {
            //the constructor implements only the properties that Passports have.
            ExpirationDate = new ExpirationDateEnabled();
            Docseries = new DocSeriesEnabled();
            DocNumber = new DocNumberEnabled();
        }
    }
    //public class PaymentOrder : Document, ILegalDocument { }
    //public class PowerOfAttorney : Document, ILegalDocument { }

    //an interface for all derived types of documents 
    public interface ILegalDocument {
        //The expiration date of a document
        public IExpirationDate ExpirationDate { get; set; }
        // serires of a document
        public IDocSeries Docseries { get; set; }
        // serial number of a document
        public IDocNumber DocNumber { get; set; }
        // a sum of money, associaned with the document
        public IMoneyAmount MoneyAmount { get; set; }
        // an exemplar of LegalSubject class (shown below) who is a signer of the document
        public ISigner Signer { get; set; }
    }
    
    public abstract class Document
    {
        //some general properties that all documents implement


        //The expiration date of a document
        public IExpirationDate ExpirationDate { get; set; }
        // serires of a document
        public IDocSeries Docseries { get; set; }
        // serial number of a document
        public IDocNumber DocNumber { get; set; }
        // a sum of money, associaned with the document
        public IMoneyAmount MoneyAmount { get; set; }
        // an exemplar of LegalSubject class (shown below) who is a signer of the document
        public ISigner Signer { get; set; }

    }
    public class LegalSubject { }

    //interfaces for the properties;
    public interface IExpirationDate
    {
        public DateTime value { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IDocSeries 
    { 
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IDocNumber
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IMoneyAmount
    {
        public decimal value { get; set; }
    }
    public interface ISigner
    {
        public LegalSubject value { get; set; }
    }

    //classes implementing the values through the interfaces shown above above
    public class ExpirationDateEnabled : IExpirationDate
    {
        public DateTime value { get; set; }
    }

    public class DocSeriesEnabled : IDocSeries
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class DocNumberEnabled : IDocNumber
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class MoneyAmountEnabled : IMoneyAmount
    {
        public decimal value { get; set; }
    }

    public class SignerEnabled : ISigner 
    {
        public LegalSubject value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ExampleLegalDocuments
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Passport testPassport = new Passport();

            if (testPassport.DocNumber is IDocNumber) { Console.WriteLine("property enabled"); } 
            else { Console.WriteLine("property not enabled"); }; //property enabled
            if (testPassport.Signer is ISigner) { Console.WriteLine("property enabled"); } 
            else { Console.WriteLine("property not enabled"); }; //property not enabled

            testPassport.DocNumber.value = "123";

            List<ILegalDocument> LegalDocuments= new List<ILegalDocument>();
            DocList.Add (testPassport);

            Console.WriteLine("Document number is {0}", LegalDocuments[0].DocNumber.value); //Document number is 123

        }
    }
}
```

Seems to work for me, though I don't like to go one level deeper to access a value, i.e. `testPassport.Documenber.value` instead of just `testPassport.value` is my approach even correct?

Comment: I don´t get your structure: once you say all documents implement the base-properties from the abstract base-class `Document`, but then you also say that e.g. a `Passport` has no `Signer`? So why is `Signer` within the base-class if not all its inheriting classes have any?

Comment: I didn't phrase myself well then. The properties (or at least interfaces for them) are in the absract class, and each concrete class can choose which of the properties it wants to implement.

Comment: OOP using inheritance is not the be-all solution to every problem, and as with every solution, there are some problems it fits well, and others it doesn't. The onus is on the developer to use the technology correct, within its limitations. In this case, if not all inherited types should have all the inherited properties, you have simply added the properties on the wrong level of the hierarchy, or you haven't split up the interfaces correctly. I would introduce something like `ISignable` with the signer property, and not introduce this in `ILegalDocument`.

Comment: And in C# you simply cannot have an inherited type without all the inherited problems. They're there, whether you want them or not. If you don't want them, you'll have to change your inheritance chain.

Comment: For the abstract base classes, my advice would be to add `public class SignableDocument : Document`, and then add the `Signer` property in there.

Comment: inheritance means: all inheriters derive everything from the base-class. Having said this, if you don´t want to implement all properties on the derived class, then the base-one should probably not contain those properties.

Comment: A different question would be if all these types share enough behavior and use to actually warrant inheritance or the same interfaces. Do you actually have to process passports and power-of-attorney documents with the same code?

Comment: Additionally, if there's no *code* in the abstract base class, what good does actually the abstract base class provide that interfaces couldn't? I would check out an all-interface solution to this, and split up the different property sets into smaller interfaces.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen *>Do you actually have to process passports and power-of-attorney documents with the same code?* At least at the userform level, I don't want to make a brand new userform to edit each of the dozens of the document types. I want my single userform to have obligatory fields for props every document have, and optional fields that I can disable/hide if there's no need for them.

Comment: The question is not which fields are obligatory, but which fields can exist on an instance of a class? Is it possible that a passport has a signer? If not, the signer-property does not belong to the base.class.

Comment: @HimBromBeere What is the best way to give the outside code  the list of properties that "might be there, but not necessarily" to iterate through and check for their existence?

Comment: Break up the interface into separate ones, then use `as IInterface` to check

Comment: there exists the `Optional`-attribute for exactly this purpose. Alternaivly just check if the property is `null`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I"m sorry, I don't know exactly what are you referring to. I only know about optional parameters of a method. Google search gave some implementations, but no definitive answer either.

Comment: @Charlieface  You mean `ILegalDocument`?

Comment: Yeah, basically, you need to split off `ISignable` from it for example, then if you want to check if it's a signable document, you can write `doc is ISignable signDoc` etc